# What is this threaded lamp(?) piece called?

Tags: light-fixture, lamp

I'm fixing a custom pendant, and one of the pieces has been damaged and needs to be replaced. Trouble is, I can't figure out what this piece is called or where to find one similar. It is the silver metal threaded piece in the photo.

[image: Threaded metal tube with one end unthreaded, and smaller with a hole in it]

- It is (almost exactly) the same diameter as an E26 light bulb base—I measure it at 1 3/32" diameter, 27.7mm. However, it has tighter threads than an E26; I measure them at 12-13 threads per inch.
- It is 1.6" / 41mm tall.
- The upper hole is 3/8" diameter, which is important as it needs to fit over "1/8 iron pipe" (3/8" diameter) and be clamped to it with nuts on either side.

The entire piece slides through a 1.25" (32mm) hole in the glass shade, and then a threaded nut/washer (like the black plastic one in the picture) screws on to support the 3-4 pound glass.

Comment: So many lamp makers, all over the world; foreign and domestic. Current and long defunct. Some using common parts, some custom, some downright one-of-a-kind. Your best bet would be a custom lamp repair shop. Good luck... I am not confident of your chances.

Comment: Yes, you're unlikely to find an equivalent part by name, let alone one that's compatible in size and shape.

Comment: Finding an exact match is unlikely.  However, it's relatively easy to find a hollow-center threaded rod with the same diameter and thread pitch, and  that may well meet your needs.  If you can't match the pitch, then you'd need to buy a washer and one or two matching nuts to 'rebuild' the support piece.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft I agree that an exact match is not needed, and I'm happy to by a new matching retainer threaded washer. Can you supply any links or name for a "hollow-center threaded rod"? You'r assertion that it's "relatively easy" may only hold true depending on what it is relative to. :) I'm not finding results using those terms. Also, note that the closed end with significantly smaller diameter is important for mounting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closest I've found is "THREADED CANDELABRA SOCKET CUP"
[image]

I'm finding a couple of similar-looking items called "lamp holder with threaded sleeve", for example:

Lamp holder E27 with threaded sleeve:
[image: Lamp holder E27 with threaded sleeve]

E27 BLACK THREADED SKIRT PENDANT STYLE LAMP HOLDER WITH 1/8IPS THREADED CAP:
[image: E27 BLACK THREADED SKIRT PENDANT STYLE LAMP HOLDER WITH 1/8IPS THREADED CAP]

E27 BLACK PHENOLIC FULLY THREADED SKIRT LAMP HOLDER WITH 1/8IPS THREADED CAP:
[image: E27 BLACK PHENOLIC FULLY THREADED SKIRT LAMP HOLDER WITH 1/8IPS THREADED CAP]